# i want to edit images on click on existing image and show preview. how to implement this?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

iam showing number of rows with images using foreach loop and i want to change image on click on existing image of a particular row .below is the code iam using

```
<td onclick="HandleBrowseClick('input-image-hidden');"><?php
echo'<img id="image-preview" style="cursor:pointer; width: 50px; 
height:50px;" 
src="' . base_url().'./uploads/admin/'. $val->member_file . '">';
?>
<input required="" name="member_file" style="display:none" id="input-image- 
hidden" onchange="document.getElementById('image-preview').src = 
window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, 
image/png"></td>
```

and the script iam using to preview image is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function HandleBrowseClick(input_image)
{
var fileinput = document.getElementById(input_image);
fileinput.click();
}     
</script>
```

iam showing rows with image using foreach and if i want to change the image on the 2nd row, iam click on the image on second row and iam select an image but the newly selected image is previewed on the first row only this is the problem. can anyone tell me a solution to solve this ie iam changing the image on the 2nd row it should preview on the 2nd row

Comment: Can you add a picture illustrating you intentions?

Comment: `id="input-image-hidden"` ... the `id` must be unique to each image.

Comment: Did you check PHPGD ?

Comment: that means i have to pass image-preview with row id ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using will output the image on the `img` tag with id `image-preview`. ID's in HTML are unique, therefore you must have only one element with id `image-preview`.

It looks like you have placed multiple `img` tags with the same ID. If that's the case, `document.getElementByID("image-preview")` will match only the first `img` tag with the id `image-preview`. Hence, your new uploaded image will always be attached to the `img` tag in the first row.

You can use the `previousSibling` property in the `onchange` attribute of your `input` to target the previous tag, i.e. `img` with id `image-preview`. Then you can change it's source attribute.

Also fix the multiple elements with same id's(Use classnames). They might break your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not passing the image id to the function HandleBrowseClick() - it is passing the image object itself - and the command document.getElementById(input_image) expects an Image ID and not an Image object

Comment: Generate unique image ids via php and pass those ids OR trap the click event, detect the image Id using 'target.id' and use that value